# How to permently delete images from Photos?

Tags: photos

I've read online to delete images from a mac which you have imported through the Photo's app that you must

1. Launch the Photos app on your Mac.
2. Go to the File > Show recently deleted menu item.
3. Click on the pictures or videos you want to permanently delete.
4. Click on the Delete button at the top right.

But I do not seem to have the option to *Show recently deleted menu item*.

[image]

Also when I check in the terminal I can see the photos still exist in the below folders

```
$ ls Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/2016/03/27/20160327-09
20160327-090437/ 20160327-091640/ 20160327-093058/ 
$ ls Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/2016/03/27/20160327-090437/
./            IMG_0073.JPG  IMG_0176.JPG  IMG_0286.JPG  IMG_0372.JPG  IMG_0481.JPG  IMG_0565.JPG  IMG_0643.JPG  IMG_0689.JPG  IMG_0758.JPG  IMG_0803.JPG  IMG_0832.AAE
../           IMG_0075.JPG  IMG_0182.JPG  IMG_0288.JPG  IMG_0376.JPG  IMG_0482.JPG  IMG_0566.JPG  IMG_0644.JPG  IMG_0690.JPG  IMG_0759.JPG  IMG_0804.AAE  IMG_0832.JPG
```

I could just delete them from the terminal but their must be a better way?  If I delete them in the terminal am I missing other places were they need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, seems recent versions of OSX put deleted photos into a *Deleted Photos* Album.

[image]

You need to click into this album and select *Delete All* in the top right hand corner.

[image]

Once I did this all the images were removed, I doubled checked in the terminal and confirmed they were deleted.